# What's the difference between collect and count actions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I was coding scala program in local-mode spark, the code is similar to `RDD.map(x => function()).collect`, there is no log output in the console for a long time and I guess it stucks. So I change the action `collect` into `count`, the whole execution completed soon. Plus, there is little records produced by the `map` phase to be collected by `collect`, so problem can't be caused by the network trans when sending back the result to the driver.

Can anyone know the reason or has run into the similar problem?

Comment: "count" works on each partition and that too in executors while collect get all data to the driver, store it in driver memory and then further perform any computations. In any case "collect" will be much slower than "count".

Answer (score 8):

The method [count](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.count) sums the number of entries of the `RDD` for every partition, and it returns an integer consisting in that number, hence the data transfer is minimal; in the other hand, the method [collect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.collect) as its name says brings all the entries to the driver as a `List` therefore if there isn't enough memory you may get several exceptions (this is why it's not recommended to do a `collect` if you aren't sure that it will fit in your driver, there are normally faster alternatives like [take](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.take), which also triggers lazy transformations), besides it requires to transfer much more data.

Comment: `take` launches jobs and there can be many jobs given data layout, i.e. the number of elements per partition.